# Avoid labels being cut at the edges in NetworkX

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I am using python networkx lib draw a node relation graph. Code like this:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([("leg", 'body'),('body', 'head'),('body','arm'),('arm','hand')])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos)
plt.show()
```

Everything is fine. The figure is:

[image]

However, I'd like to put the label outside of the node. Then I adjust the position of labels. code is:

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([("leg", 'body'),('body', 'head'),('body','arm'),('arm','hand')])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
# nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = {k:([v[0], v[1]+0.1]) for k,v in pos.items()})

plt.show()
```

Then the figure is:

[image]

The question is, the label do not display totally, but exceed the boundary. so how can I display the labels normally? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `scale` parameter in [`nx.spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) to a low value to scale down the positions. It basically applies a scale factor to the node positions, so the nodes are positioned in a box of size `[0,scale]`. Here's an example:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=0.2)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos)
y_off = 0.02
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = {k:([v[0], v[1]+y_off]) for k,v in pos.items()})
```

[image]