# How to force netwrokx to expand image to fit labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

Minimum working example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge("aLongLabel", "anotherLongLabel")
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True )
```

[Produces this image with the labels cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDrA1.png)

I think networkx is using matplotlib under the hood, and I have read you can use plt.tight_layout() to call to force a normal plot to resize, but I am not seeing how to push that through networkx, or if there is another way instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid labels being cut at the edges in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61985381/networks-draw-networkx-labels-do-not-display-all-nodes-labels-when-i-put-the-l/61987572#61987572)

Comment: perfect, thankyou! didn't find it on the first search.